# Sorting a dictionary by key using the import Library returns sorted values only for the first digit

Tags: python, python-3.x

Program Description:

- Read The student's name and marks and store it in a dictionary
- Rank the Students by the Dictionary value
- Give cash rewards to top 3 students based on rank
- write appreciation to the students who have scored more than 950 marks

[image]

I have used the operator library to sort my dictionary for Students Marks record Program but as I am sorting the dictionary based on the marks, It seems to be sorting the dictionary only based on the first digit (from left to right) as shown below:

[image]

For example if the marks provided is 700,80,9 it sorts the marks as 9,80,700.
I am guessing the code is just checking for the first digit and if it is found to be greater than the first digit of another number (though second number it is greater than the first number), the first number is only shown to be greater.

Comment: Next time, copy-paste your code and error message (if any) as text.

Comment: @Austin What do you mean, "next time"? The current question can and should be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are inputting the number as string. As you can see the dict shows the numbers in quotes. You have to get the number input as wither int or float.

```
value = int(input("enter the value: "))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're sorting based on string values, not integer values. You need to convert your marks to integers. When sorting by integer, 855 > 9. When sorting as though they were strings, this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

First, dont upload screenshots of your code. Use the code sample icon on the editor to post the actual code. Also include just the function that has the problem - rank.

All the following code is at the top of your `rank` function.

First, convert the numeric element of each tuple to an int:

```
students2 = [(a,int(b)) for (a,b) in student]
```

Then replace `ranked = sorted(students.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)`

with `sorted(student2, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)`

As a bonus, no need for the operator dependency.